# FTP MGET Cannot find the file specified?

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am using the batch file code below to try and download a folder called "Presentation" When I run this it gives me the error that it cannot find the file specified about 7 times(There are 7 items in the presentation folder. Is my syntax wrong?

```
@Echo Off
Set _FTPServerName= 
Set _UserName=FTPUser
Set _Password=enter4FTP
Set _LocalFolder= C:\Users
Set _Filename= Presentation
Set _ScriptFile=ftp1
:: Create script
>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo open %_FTPServerName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %_LocalFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo binary
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo prompt
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo mget %_Filename%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo quit
:: Run script
ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"
Del "%_ScriptFile%"
pause
```

Comment: Why do you have a space before Presentation?

Comment: I changed that still the same error but I added a "/" in front of presentation and it grabbed the files. But it wont grab the sub directories?